# What does this mean: 更不是被告?

Tags: translation

Does it mean "not the defendant"? The translation I have available (which isn't mine) is the following: "let alone the defendant", so which of us, if any, is correct?

Comment: 更 makes the negation stronger. Eg. 我不是老师, 更不是教授！

Comment: @Dan As I stated in my answer, 更 means "in addition" or "specifically" . It doesn't only emphasize negation , it  emphasizes everything. For example: "作為老師要有學識，更要有耐性" ,  "他有青春，更有熟情"

Comment: @TangHo I kind of disagree that 更 in this context means "specifically". It's closer to the sense "more on", "more to" or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"not the defendant" is just "不是被告"

"let alone the defendant" in Chinese is "更不必提被告"  or "更不用說被告"

"**更**不是被告" means "**specifically** not the defendant"

Example:

他不是被告 = he is not the defendant

次被告也判死刑, 更不必提被告 = even the second defendant is sentenced to death, not to mention (let alone) the defendant. -- *of course he has to be sentenced to death*

犯案的不是陳某或張某, 更不是被告 = The one who committed the crime is not Chen or Zhang, certainly (specifically) not the defendant.

Comment: Thanks for your help.